# Google Maps / JavaScript - display certain markers - MySQL backend

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have a web page that is displaying markers on a Google Map.
The markers are stored in a MySQL DB.
The values are retrieved into an XML file via with PHP.

Full instructions are here:
https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3

So far so good:
http://www.pizzazzle.co.uk/maps/phpAndMySQL.php

I have added two tick boxes for my two "types" of pin.

I want to display only the relevant markers that belong to the types that are checked.

So if all types are ticked all pins display. If only "bar" is ticked, only the pins with type "bar" should display.

I'm scratching my head trying to work out how to get this to function. Mainly because I'm not that familiar with JavaScript - I am a PHP guy really.

Any ideas would be great.

The code for the page so far is below. I've now added the full working code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <title>PHP/MySQL & Google Maps Example</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[

//set up globals
var gmarkers = [];
var infoWindow = [];

//set up icons
var customIcons = {
restaurant: {
icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_blue.png'
},
bar: {
icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png'
}
};


//load function
function load() {

//initialise map
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
center: new google.maps.LatLng(47.6145, -122.3418),
zoom: 13,
mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
});
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
//ok



//set up pins from xmlgen.php file
  // Change this depending on the name of your PHP file
downloadUrl("xmlgen.php", function(data) {
  var xml = data.responseXML;
  var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
  for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
    var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
    var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
    var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
        parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
        parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
    var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
    var icon = customIcons[type] || {};

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: point,
      icon: icon.icon
    });
    marker.mycategory = type;
    gmarkers.push(marker);

    bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
}
  });
}

    function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infoWindow.setContent(html);
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
      });
    }

    function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
      var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
          new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
          new XMLHttpRequest;

      request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
          request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
          callback(request, request.status);
        }
      };

      request.open('GET', url, true);
      request.send(null);
    }

    function doNothing() {}


// == shows all markers of a particular category, and ensures the checkbox is checked ==
 function show(category) {
   for (var i=0; i<gmarkers.length; i++) {
     if (gmarkers[i].mycategory == category) {
       gmarkers[i].setVisible(true);
     }
   }
   // == check the checkbox ==
   document.getElementById(category+"box").checked = true;
 }

 // == hides all markers of a particular category, and ensures the checkbox is cleared ==
 function hide(category) {
   for (var i=0; i<gmarkers.length; i++) {
     if (gmarkers[i].mycategory == category) {
       gmarkers[i].setVisible(false);
     }
   }
   // == clear the checkbox ==
   document.getElementById(category+"box").checked = false;
   // == close the info window, in case its open on a marker that we just hid
   infoWindow.close();
 }

 // == a checkbox has been clicked ==
      function boxclick(box,category) {
        if (box.checked) {
          show(category);
        } else {
          hide(category);
        }
      }

    //]]>

  </script>

  </head>

<body onload="load()">

<div id="map" style="width: 700px; height: 500px"></div>

<form action="#">
<input type="checkbox" id="restaurantbox" onclick="boxclick(this,'restaurant')" checked/>
<label>restaurant</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="barbox" onclick="boxclick(this,'bar')" checked/>
<label>bar</label>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The [classic "categories" map](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_MW_example_categories.html) (translated to v3 from [Mike Williams' v2 tutorial](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/categories.htm))

Comment: @geocodezip thank you for the tip on the article. I have added the onclick events and the functions they call. I'm getting a console error saying that 'markers' are not defined. I think its talking about the markers in the 'hide' and 'show' functions. http://www.pizzazzle.co.uk/maps/phpAndMySQL-with%20checkboxes.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem at present is that the only "markers" in you code is local to the downloadUrl callback function, it is the array of xml objects that comes from:

var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");

The boxclick function, which is a HTML onclick function, runs in the global scope, and you need an array of google.maps.Marker objects in that (global scope) to call hide/show on.

1. add a global gmarkers array (outside of any function):

   ```
   var gmarkers = [];
   var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({}); // update, global infoWindow
   ```
2. push the google.maps.Markers onto that array as you create them:

   ```
   // Change this depending on the name of your PHP file
   downloadUrl("xmlgen.php", function(data) {
     var xml = data.responseXML;
     var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
     for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
       var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
       var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
       var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
       var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
           parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
           parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
       var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
       var icon = customIcons[type] || {};

       var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
         map: map,
         position: point,
         icon: icon.icon
       });
       marker.mycategory = type;
       gmarkers.push(marker);

       bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
   }
   ```
3. change your hide and show functions to use the gmarkers array:

   ```
   // == shows all markers of a particular category, and ensures the checkbox is checked ==
    function show(category) {
      for (var i=0; i<gmarkers.length; i++) {
        if (gmarkers[i].mycategory == category) {
          gmarkers[i].setVisible(true);
        }
      }
      // == check the checkbox ==
      document.getElementById(category+"box").checked = true;
    }

    // == hides all markers of a particular category, and ensures the checkbox is cleared ==
    function hide(category) {
      for (var i=0; i<gmarkers.length; i++) {
        if (gmarkers[i].mycategory == category) {
          gmarkers[i].setVisible(false);
        }
      }
      // == clear the checkbox ==
      document.getElementById(category+"box").checked = false;
      // == close the info window, in case its open on a marker that we just hid
      infoWindow.close();
    }
   ```

Comment: thanks @geocodezip. I have made the changes you suggested. I am now getting a GET error. There is not much more information than that. Live demo: http://pizzazzle.co.uk/maps/phpAndMySQL-with%20checkboxes2.html

Comment: ...i forgot to mention, I have updated the code at the top to reflaect the changes you suggested @geocodezip

Comment: My answer had a typo (infowindow should have been infoWindow) and wasn't adding the "mycategory" property to the marker.  Fixed.

Comment: excellent @geocodezip. That's working now. I noticed in the Crome Console that i get a couple of errors. Are these normal or should i try to resolve them? One is a 'GET' error and the other is an 'Uncaught Reference Error'. I don't normally get errors when I am coding in PHP.

Comment: I don't see the 'GET' error.  The "infoWindow" needs to be defined in the global scope (like the gmarkers array).

Comment: thanks @geocodezip, Ive added to global scope, but still errors. the errors only come up when i click on one of the check boxes: http://pizzazzle.co.uk/maps/phpAndMySQL-with%20checkboxes2.html

Comment: You need to move this line `var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;` into the global scope (and remove the local version from your "load" function.  Your code is currently creating a global array named infoWindow, which isn't useful.